# xcode 6 beta 4 is not launching in Mavericks 10.9.3

Tags: xcode

I just downloaded Xcode beta4 yesterday and installed it in Maverick 10.9.4 but after installing Xcode didn't run at all and it didn't even give any error message. Then i read Xcode beta 4 release note and there it was mentioned that required OS is either 10.9.3 or 10.10.

Now have downgraded my OS to 10.9.3 and reinstalled the Xcode again but still its not running. In the dock the application will just jump once and then nothing will happen.

What should i do to check the problem or get the error message so that i can work on it.

Comment: SO may be not the right place ?

Comment: Sorry i couldn't understand. I downloaded the Xcode beta 4 from developer.apple.com

Comment: I don't think stackoverflow is the place for software troubleshooting